# F test for multiple samples

Tags: r, statistics

I have 3 data series A, B, C, D and E. How do I test whether the averages across A and B AND B and C etc. are jointly equal to one another using an F-test. I want to do this in R.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make up data:

```
A <- runif(100); B <- runif(100); C <- runif(100)
```

Collapse it into a data frame:

```
d <- data.frame(group=rep(c("A","B","C"),each=100),y=c(A,B,C))
```

Run a 1-way ANOVA:

```
anova(lm(y~group,data=d))
## Analysis of Variance Table
## 
## Response: y
##            Df  Sum Sq  Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
## group       2  0.2346 0.117310  1.3734 0.2548
## Residuals 297 25.3677 0.085413
```